# How do i print a variable without getting brackets in python

Tags: python

Here is my code below if i print it directly i'm not getting any brackets or commas whereas if i store it in a variable and print the variable its getting printed in brackets.

If anyone know to print it without brackets please let me know

**Code:**

```
user_name = input('Your Name')
user_year =  int(input('Your Birth Year'))
user_age = 2021 - user_year
user_info = "Age of",user_name,"is",user_age

print(user_info)
print('Age of',user_name,'is',user_age)
```

**Output:**

```
Your Name Sri Govind
Your Birth Year 2005
('Age of', ' Sri Govind', 'is', 16)
Age of  Sri Govind is 16

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: oh i added an image

Comment: @SriGovind don't post image of your code. post it as text

Comment: i mean i want to show the output too

Comment: you can show output as text as well

Comment: yeah i edited the post
im new to this web actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user_info = "Age of",user_name,"is",user_age` this will actually create a tuple. try `print(type(user_info))`.
you can do `user_info = "Age of "+user_name+" is "+str(user_age)`. This will make it string.

Answer (score 2):

Inputting the value of the variables in the string is straightforward.

### String Formatting

```
user_info = "Age of {name} is {age}".format(name=user_name, age=user_age)
```

### f Strings

```
user_info = f"Age of {user_name} is {user_age}"
```

Comment: it also worked thank you too :D

Answer (score 1):

for these lines :

```
user_info = "Age of",user_name,"is",user_age

print(user_info)
```

for get all value you can use `*` like below:

```
print(*user_info)
```

you can also use f-strings like below:

```
user_info = f"Age of {user_name} is {user_age}"

print(user_info)
```

Comment: @SriGovind, did you see this answer?

Comment: This too worked thank you too :D
it helped me very much
just a small change but a lot efficient

Comment: @SriGovind welcome dude why get `accept`